# How to Pretty/Awesome Print Response from Google API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I get the following response from a success call to the Gmail API:

```
#<Google::Apis::GmailV1::Profile:0x00007f9ad2160210 @email_address="email@example.com", @history_id=15581926, @messages_total=174760, @threads_total=127619>
```

However, when I print it to the console using either awesome_print or pretty print (both of which output the expected format with a test such as `User.first`) it doesn't reformat the response to a readable format.

I have tried

`ap JSON.parse(response)`

and I get

`no implicit conversion of Google::Apis::GmailV1::Profile into String`

I'm certain that I'm not understanding the format of the response from the API and what awesome_print is expecting. Is there a way that I can parse the response in such a way that makes it more readable in the console?

Comment: try `ap response.to_h` I mistyped this issue is `JSON` cannot turn it into a `String`

Comment: `ap response.to_h` worked! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the response to a hash is the solution.

```
ap response.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Google::Apis::GmailV1::Profile`](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/generated/google/apis/gmail_v1/classes.rb#L1053) is a simple class that does not implement anything to help it’s pretty printing (save for `to_h`, see below.)

You might do it yourself though:

```
Google::Apis::GmailV1::Profile.prepend(Module.new do
  def pp
    %i|email_address history_id messages_total threads_total|.map do |attr|
      [attr, public_send(attr)]
    end.to_h
  end
end)
```

and use `response.pp` to pretty print it. Or, alternatively, simply use what it provides by default: `response.to_h`.

Comment: Your overwriting an existing method [`Google::Apis::GmailV1::Profile#to_h`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/GmailV1/Profile)

Comment: @engineersmnky oh, indeed, I did not notice `include` statement.